# Is it ever correct to use "relate to with"?

Tags: word-choice

The following is a sentence I used -

> Read these stories. See how many you can **relate to with** your own childhood

Somehow this *relate to with* was there in my subconscious mind, but now I feel it is not correct. Should I use *relate to/with* instead?

Comment: It is a little awkward, perhaps, but it would certainly not consider it wrong. You could perhaps say something like, “See how many you can relate to through examples from your childhood”, but I'm not sure that would really improve things.

Answer (score 3):

Using *relate to* or *relate with* is certainly correct. Using *relate to with your own childhood* is also correct as it can be interpreted as *relate to using your own childhood*.

Comment: Group therapy is often put forward as being a good way of tackling certain mental disorders, showing the sufferer that he is not alone. But how many fellow sufferers can one be expected to relate to with sociophobia? However, I don't think OP's juxtaposition of particle/preposition sounds really idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you give I think you should just remove the 'with'. It makes perfectly good sense without it and I believe it says exactly what you want to say.

Answer (score -1):

I am glad an answer above encourages me to say *relate with*  instead of *relate to* because *with* implies closeness whereas *to* implies distance.

Comment: I find "... can relate with your own childhood" a bit confusing, and it seems to change the sense of the sentence.  But the original is a hair confusing as well -- probably needs to be reworded more extensively.